# Rabbitmq doesn't start with docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm facing next problem. I want to run rabbitmq in docker container. When I run docker image with next command:

`docker run -it --rm  --name rabbit -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=aaa -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=aaa -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

It works just fine.
But I cannot run it in docker-compose. There is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=aaa
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=aaa
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
```

I use `docker-compose up --build` command. Logs are ok, but I cannot open rabbitmq at `localhost:15672`.

Versions are:

`docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064`

`Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838`

#### Edit

I think, logs are fine, but I'm not sure. Please, check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/Podidiving/e49c30478c7b30eb445afdc51b5812d2)

Comment: https://github.com/Gsantomaggio/rabbitmqexample/blob/master/cluster_docker_compose/cluster_conf/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Your example `docker-compose.yml` works fine for me with no changes. I note that there is a bit of delay between starting the container and rabbitmq actually being ready to service requests.

Comment: Yes, I've waited for several minutes, and still no changes...

Comment: looks like rabbitmq starting up. please check host IP and try opening port using that instead of localhost

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry to bump this one up a year later, but I've just ran into the same problem, so I hope it helps someone anyway :)

**TL;DR**
Using the *rabbitmq:3-management-alpine* image **instead of** *rabbitmq:3-management* solved this for me.

Here is my *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  my-rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: my-rabbit
    hostname: my-rabbit-host
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - "./rabbitdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq"
```

After running `docker compose --detach` the management plugin interface and the broker itself become available at http://localhost:15672 (tcp localhost:5672 for broker)

**The long story**

Using **rabbitmq:3-management** image with docker-compose.yml produces the following output in docker logs:
[image: Log output for rabbitmq:3-management with docker-compose.yml]

The output stops after the last line

```
01 19:20:07.852760+00:00 [noti] <0.299.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
```

and neither broker nor management plugin are available.

However, after running the following command (using the same arguments as in docker-compose.yml)

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit-host -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name my-rabbit -v rabbitdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management
```

the log actually looks quite different:

[image: Docker log after running rabbitmq:3-management using shell command]

One might notice, that the server is actually started, and after that both broker and management UI become accessible!

Now, if we change the image in docker-compose.yml from **rabbitmq:3-management** to **rabbitmq:3-management-alpine** (see TL;DR example) and run `docker compose up --detach`, the log output looks pretty much like it was with `docker run ... rabbitmq:3-management`, and, once again, both broker interface and the management plugin interface work just fine at localhost using ports 5672 and 15672 respectively.

Comment: thx so much.. i've been struggling with this for 2 days..geez

Answer (score 1):

Please wait for while sometime rabbitmq take times to start up try this working for me

```
version: "3"

services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    command: rabbitmq-server
    expose:
      - 5672
      - 15672
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "5672" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 1

  worker:
    image: worker
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Comment: Yeah, I've waited, but nothing changed. Can you, please, check out my log file? Maybe there is an issue, which I don't see

Answer (score 1):

Running RabbitMQ using **docker-compose.yml** is quiet simple

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.2-management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: rabbitmq-host
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

you can simply start the docker compose file by using the command

```
docker-compose up
```

wait for 30 seconds and hit http://localhost:15672/ in you browser. You can use guest as both default username and password. You can find a sample Spring Boot RabbitMQ example in the below GitHub

https://github.com/nidhishkrishnan/messaging